# Read each number from array and making sum

Tags: vb.net

I am kinda new at coding.
I am reading some numbers from a txt files and i have them into a array,i managed to make them descending,now i want to make a sum with this numbers,for example:
I will have an input number 1000,on the list i will have numbers from 100 to 1000 and i want to make a sum with them to reach 1000 with minimum rest.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fStream As New System.IO.FileStream("C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\test.txt", IO.FileMode.Open)
    Dim sReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fStream)
    Dim List As New List(Of Double)
    Do While sReader.Peek >= 0
        List.Add(sReader.ReadLine)
    Loop
    Dim i As Long
    Dim txt As String
    Dim thisArray As Double() = List.ToArray
    For i = LBound(thisArray) To UBound(thisArray)
        txt = thisArray(i) & vbCrLf
    Next i
    Array.Sort(thisArray)
    For j As Integer = 0 To thisArray.Count - 1
        Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\Users\Alex\desktop\test2.txt"

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then

            Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, IO.FileMode.Append)

            objWriter.WriteLine(thisArray(j))
            objWriter.Close()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("File Does Not Exist")
        End If
    Next
    fStream.Close()
    sReader.Close()
End Sub
```

I dont know where to start to do this..input number will be from a textbox.

Comment: You should enclose your `FileStream` in a `Using` block, or explicitly call its `Dispose` method. Ditto for everything that implements the `IDisposable` interface. I've re-tagged your question to [tag:vb.net], because [tag:vba] is a completely different thing.

Comment: That said this looks like a lot of responsibilities for a `Click` handler. *Once you get your code to work as intended*, I'd suggest you post your working code (heck, the whole form's code-behind) on [codereview.se] to get feedback on every aspect of your code - you'll learn a ton!

Comment: Turn on `Option Strict`.  this: `txt = thisArray(i) & vbCrLf` is assigning a number to a string.  You also dont need to convert the List ToArray() in order to iterate it